# Does the ring of continuous functions determine $\mathbb R^n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, ring-theory, category-theory, continuous-homomorphisms

I have two related questions which are just making the question asked in the title more specific:

(a) *Is every ring homomorphism (or maybe $\mathbb R$-algebra homorphism) between rings of the form $\mathscr C(\mathbb R^n),$ ie. rings of continuous functions on Euclidean spaces, automatically continuous?*

(b) *Does the obvious functor $\mathbb R^n\mapsto \mathscr C(\mathbb R^n)$ define a fully faithful embedding of the full subcategory of topological spaces spanned by $\mathbb R^n$ for all $n,$ into the category of (if needs be topological, depending on what the answer to (a) is) rings/algebras?*

I am aware that the answer to both questions is positive when attention is restricted to smooth functions or, when $n$ is even and we can identify $\mathbb R^n$ with $\mathbb C^{n/2},$ to holomorphic or even regular (in the sense of algebraic geometry) functions. However, it is the continuous case which interests me.

Comment: Continuous with respect to which topology? Uniform convergence?

Comment: Really I had in mind the compact-open topology - I am told it is the standard topology to consider on function spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two relevant theorems from [Gillman and Jerison, Rings of Continuous Functions, Van Nostrand 1960](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4615-7819-2):

**Theorem 8.3.** Two realcompact spaces $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic if and only if $C(X)$ and $C(Y)$ are isomorphic as rings.

**Theorem 10.6.** Let $t:C(Y) \to C(X)$ be a ring homomorphism with the property that $t\mathbf{1} = \mathbf{1}$. If $Y$ is realcompact, then there exists a unique continuous mapping $\tau:X \to Y$ such that $tf=f\circ \tau$ for all $f \in C(Y)$.

The definition of realcompactness is a little involved, but every Lindelöf space is realcompact, so all subsets of Euclidean spaces are, too. This shows that the answer to both of your questions is "yes".

Comment: Thank you, this is absolutely splendid! If I get this right, this shows that my questions have an affirmative answer even if, instead of Euclidean spaes, I asked it for all topological manifolds?

Comment: @user29124: If the topological manifold is second-countable, then yes. I am not quite sure whether it works for all topological manifolds.